# word count error in Python using Anaconda Jupyter

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to count words using the Python script below.

```
import os
os.chdir('D:\ECP\TAT')
filename = 'D:\ECP\TAT\Test.txt'
numlines = 0


with open (filename,'r') as file:
    for l in file:
        Wordlist = l.split()
        numlines+=1

print("Wordlist")
```

But I am getting the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\ECP\\TAT\\Test.txt'

IDE : Anaconda (Jupyter) python : 3.6
```

Comment: tried escaping the `\\`? and ``print(Wordlist)`

Comment: @VanPeer: tried. but no luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
os.chdir('D:\\ECP\\TAT\\')
filename = 'D:\\ECP\\TAT\\Test.txt'
numlines = 0

with open (filename,'r') as file:
    for l in file:
        Wordlist = l.split()
        numlines+=1

print(Wordlist)
```

Comment: same error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\ECP\\TAT\\Test.txt'

Comment: C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe
from jupyter notebook.